# Python pypyodbc cursor (data) to excel sheet

Tags: python, xlwings, database-cursor, pypyodbc

I have obtained a cursor (data recordset) from sql server using pypyodbc.  I have xlwings library and have spawned a workbook.  I can simply loop through each row of the cursor and write the fields of the records one by one to excel cells... I want to know if there is a better/faster way of getting this data onto the excel sheet.

With the immense number of python libraries and function I thought that there would be a better way to get data from the cursor to the excel sheet rather than loop cell by cell.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks.

I have tried looping for each row and for each column.  Is there a better wa?

Comment: If the data is converted to lists then each can be written across a row per the Xlwings documentation `sheet['A1'].value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` will write the 5 numbers across row 1 i.e. A1:E1. But maybe it would be better to convert to a dataframe and use (Pandas) ExcelWriter to write the lot to the sheet in one go.